# Animation inside jetpack compose draw scope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I was trying to implement two different animations inside a `drawScope`:

1. `clipRect` (as the first part on a path)
2. `slideInVertically` (as second part on a drawable, as shown in the table [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#enter-exit-transition))

I was able to implement the `clipRect` part with the help of [this video](https://youtu.be/1yiuxWK74vI?t=490) but I am stuggling with the `slideInVertically` implementation. So is there anyway we can achieve it particularly in `drawScope`?

Also there is another general question around jetpack compose animation: 
If I want to try out all of [these animations](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#enter-exit-transition) inside a `drawScope` is there any documentation that can help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`traslate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).translate(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Function1)) function along with [`animateTo`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/value-based#animatable) function to `slideInVertically` effect.

It goes like:

```
val translateBy = remember {Animatable(initialValue = 0f)}

LaunchedEffect(Unit){
    translateBy.animateTo(targetValue = 1f, animationSpec = tween(2000)
}
...
...
{ // drawScope
    translate (100.dp.toPx()*translateBy.value){
        drawImageFromDrawable(this /*drawScope*/, imagesList) // function to draw image from drawable
    }
}
```

For the general question:

> If I want to try out all of these animations inside a drawScope is there any documentation that can help me with it?

Leaving some animations like `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` others can be achieved by using different combination of [`traslate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).translate(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Function1)) and [`scale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).scale(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset,kotlin.Function1)) functions along with `if else` statements.